# EPSON XP-235 Expression Home printer installed but WONT JUST PRINT

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, scanner, sony

So I recently got an Epson XP-235 Expression Home printer and I have tried everything to the best of my ability, but IT WONT JUST PRINT. My computer is a  Sony vaio with a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 operating system. In the "printers - localhost" panel, it shows that EPSON-XP-235-Series is active and its available, but I still can not print a document. The paper just rolls over with blanks. I will be very grateful to receive any step-by-step solution in solving this problem.

Cheers
Bob

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/03/11/how-to-download-install-epson-xp-235-series-printer-drivers-software-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-lts-gnu-linux/

Comment: Yes I did. I uninstalled what I had previously, and followed the step in the link you provided again, but only downloaded this generic .deb version. (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule). It wasn't available on Ubuntu software center. Also downloaded Mtink. Afterwards restarted everything and finally got a print out. Many Thanks as well...